Проблемы с импортом на сайт CS-CART 1C
Всем привет возникла такая проблема, что сайт перестал отображать корректно наличие товара, его остатки.
Подскажите куда копать?
Используется 1С - и магазин построен на Laravel, и использованием CRM CS-CART
